# How to stop Google Chrome's resource mapping from screwing up the indentation of CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

So I might be one of the few people who indent their CSS, regardless, using Google Chrome's resource mapping to edit local files strips the closing bracket on my CSS declarations:

[image]

Is there anything I can do here to make sure Chrome respects my indentation?

Comment: Do you use tab spacing for CSS?

Comment: Chrome is probably converting your tabs. Use 2-space indents and it should be fine.